# Checking if MATLAB is running in multithread mode

Tags: matlab

The [documentation states](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/matlabwindows.html) that MATLAB can be launched in single-thread mode as follows:

```
matlab -singleCompThread
```

My question is: Is there a way to reliably check from within MATLAB if it's running in this mode or in the default multi-thread mode?

We have access to a remote cluster where depending on the queue the jobs are sent and the availability of computing resources, MATLAB may start in `singleCompThread` mode, and it would be great if we could tell this from within MATLAB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For now, you can use `maxNumCompThreads`, though it warns it will be removed in a future release. In singleCompThread mode, it will return 1. (At least on Windows, where I tested it.)

Answer (score 2):

On 2011a (what I'm running) the following works:

```
maxNumCompThreads
```

However, the documentation indicates that it's deprecated, and will be removed from future versions.