# How to enable multithreading in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Some of MATLAB's functions support multithreading and will make use of your multi-core architecture when available. Hence, I'm not referring to MATLAB support for parallel execution when you explicitly invoke it, e.g. using parfor.

In my code I'm running imregtform. My issue with using this function is that on one device (Win 8, x64, MATLAB 2014b) the function (called thousands of times) is maxing all my CPUs but whereas on another device (Win 7, x64, MATLAB 2014a) it is barely using half of my CPUs and only about 20%. Why is that? Is there a switch somewhere?

If tried some of the suggestions found in:
[Checking if MATLAB is running in multithread mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012731/checking-if-matlab-is-running-in-multithread-mode) and [Matlab 2011a Use all Cores Available on 64 bit Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191403/matlab-2011a-use-all-cores-available-on-64-bit-linux).

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe multithreading for this function was implemented with version 2014b? Did you try other functions which support multithreading?

Comment: My mistake, both are running 2014b so that's not the issue.

Comment: What does `feature numcores` return on those devices? MATLAB does not consider hyperthreaded cores as these are known not to provide additional speed-up.

Comment: It returns the following 
MATLAB detected: 4 physical cores.
MATLAB detected: 8 logical cores.
MATLAB was assigned: 8 logical cores by the OS.
MATLAB is using: 4 logical cores.
MATLAB is not using all logical cores because hyper-threading is enabled.
on the system where it takes a lot longer to process the data and
MATLAB detected: 2 physical cores.
MATLAB detected: 4 logical cores.
MATLAB was assigned: 4 logical cores by the OS.
MATLAB is using: 2 logical cores.
MATLAB is not using all logical cores because hyper-threading is enabled.
on the system where all cores are maxed during processing.