# Can I use parfor within a parfeval in Matlab R2019b and if yes how?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor, matlab-gui

I'm encountering an issue with my MATLAB R2019b GUI project. I'm trying to display two sets of 4DCT (Four-Dimensional Computed Tomography) images simultaneously. Each set contains 10 CT volumes. While displaying the first case(two sets), I want to asynchronously load additional sets in the background. My approach involves using `parfeval(@select_data, x, data{idx})` for each 4DCT, where select_data is a function utilizing `parfor` to read the 10 DICOM volumes.

When I run `select_data` independently, it performs well, utilizing all available workers efficiently (e.g., 12 workers). However, when I use `parfeval`, only one additional worker is utilized, leading to slower loading times (about 30-40 seconds per 4DCT). Also it causes lag in the main thread, even though I expect multiple workers to be employed for the loading process and the rest available for my main.

Here are the server specs I have access to:

```
CPU(s): 24
Thread(s) per core: 2
Core(s) per socket: 6
Socket(s): 2
```

Memory: 70GB

I've attempted to limit the number of workers to 8 in the parpool, leaving 4 cores free to handle the main GUI thread, but the lag persists.

It's possible that the issue lies with the usage of `parfor` within `parfeval`, which might not be leveraging all available workers as expected?

Edit: Using parfor within a parfeval is **not possible**, parfor will be processed as a normal for-loop if called by parfeval.

Answer (score 3):

You certainly can use `parfor` in the functions invoked using `parfeval`. It is difficult to do this in a non-trivial manner in R2019b though. In later releases of MATLAB (>=R2020a), you can use a [thread pool](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.threadpool.html) inside each local process worker. It's awkward to set up though, and even then there might be challenges getting everything you need running on thread-pool workers.

The approach I would explore is converting your `select_data` so that you can run it directly in chunks inside `parfeval`. I.e. instead of something like this

```matlab
function out = select_data(in)
    parfor i = 1:n
        out(i) = dostuff(i);
    end
end
```

You somehow work out how many iterates you need and then effectively call the guts of the `parfor` loop directly from the client via `parfeval`, like this:

```matlab
for i = 1:n
   fut(i) = parfeval(@dostuff, 1, i);
end
fetchOutputs(fut);
```

This also would let you use e.g. [`afterAll`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parallel.future.afterall.html) on the array of futures to do something else asynchronously once the work is all finished.

Comment: There was a recent video blog on this exact topic here: https://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2024/03/20/switching-a-parfor-to-a-parfeval/

Comment: I tried something like this but still have the performance issues during the loading in the background. I dont necessarly need the speed up anymore for the subsequent volumes but I need to ensure that my GUI remains responsive. For instance, users should still be able to scroll through slices and switch phases seamlessly while working with the initially opened case. And currently I dont understand how parfeval has an influence on my main thread(scrolling etc) because in my understanding it should be a completly new thread and also the variables used are not shared with the main thread.

Comment: Had a conversion with one of the developers for the parallel computing toolbox and sadly it is not possible to use a parfor within a parfeval. The parfor then will be evaluated/processed in a sequential manner. But still thanks!
Link to his answer:
https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2099541-can-i-use-parfor-within-parfeval-in-matlabr2019b-and-if-yes-how#comment_3112246

PS: I hope it was not a problem to ask this question in two different forums, just though the chances for an answer would be higher.

Comment: @max_hid Hm, Damian's comment isn't quite the full story. It _is_ possible as I outline above, but it is currently pretty awkward. It's definitely not possible (without a MATLAB Parallel Server license) in R2019b.

Answer (score 2):

I expect nesting parallel structures to not yield any additional speed-up. You can assign a number of workers to the outer parallellisation, which doesn't leave any room to use even more workers from outside the current, already parallel, outer level. In any case, [it's recommended to parallelise the *outermost* loop](https://mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/nested-parfor-loops-and-for-loops.html) in case of nested loops, I expect the same to hold true for nesting other parallellisation structures.

In case your outer structure only contains two elements (i.e. your `idx` is `2`), you might be better off by serially evaluating that loop and using parallellisation on the reading, since you've already verified that that does indeed use more workers and thus reduces execution time.

There's a bunch of background links on how and when to leverage parallellisation in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72527420/5211833) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32146700/5211833).

There's an example in the [`parfeval` docs](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.pool.parfeval.html;jsessionid=f754d31761563b9c189c8970882b#mw_56da3b6f-532f-45bf-bd30-4b01f5f64bf3) that updates a UI, that might be worth a try. Alternatively, you could try [`spmd()`](https://mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/spmd.html) to parallellise your reading and assign a limited number of workers to each SPMD. Given you have two sockets with 6 workers each, I'd set the number of workers to 6, leaving a single socket for the main thread:

```matlab
parpool(6)
spmd
    your_code()
end
```

Comment: The problem with serially evaluating the loop over all my cases and using parallellisation(parfor) on the reading is that I'm blocking my main thread doing that. So I though using parfeval would be a good opportunity. And blocking the main thread would be an absolute no-go for my project. Is there any way of making sure that parfeval is not influecing my main thread? Because I could live with slower loading times but not with lagged visualization.

Comment: To run parallel tasks asynchronously you might want to [`createJob()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/createjob.html) to build up a bunch of tasks and then dispatch them to the local MATLAB cluster, with or without waiting on them to finish before doing something else